# AngularJs controller add all html elements from template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to add all my elements from my template to my $scope.
I want them to be accessible like c# or java elements in the code.

for example
if i have this HTML template

```
<div ch-options-div id="chOptions" ng-controller="chOptionsCtrl">
    <span>Options</span>
    <div id="chOptionsWrapper">

        <div id="div1">
        </div>

        <div id="div2"></div>
        <div id="div3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is a possible controller:

```
var chOptions = angular.module('chOptions',[]);

chOptions.controller('chOptionsCtrl', function ($scope,$document,$element) 
{     
    //select all elements by id and add them to scope
    $scope.chOptionsWrapper = document.getElementById('chOptionsWrapper');
    //or with jquery
    $scope.div1 = $('#div1')
}
```

Is there a best case to do this or is there a good way to add all my HTML elements to the scope ? I want clean "object oriented" javascript code.

Comment: You can access anything within the controller using selectors. eg `$('#div1')`. Why are you doing this though? If you are going to manipulate the elements, its best to do it in a directive

Comment: That would be the opposite of a clean "object-oriented" code. You should respect the Model-View-Controller approach, where all the View stays in your HTML and is updated according to your model (the $scope).

Comment: okay i have a background color of a div and want to manipulate it because it is used as a color preview how would that be done without knowing the element ? can i acces div1 or div2 in my directive "ch-options-div" ?

Comment: Theres multiple ways to do that. If you do no want to go down the directive path, you can do it the 'angular way' by manipulating a model and applying it to a property like ng-class. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/skriblez/dqfwvyso/

Comment: nice example :) i would use it but the colours are variable so i have RGB values and i don't think i can add a model to the css, and i don't want the css directly in my html code otherwise i would have solved this with a "style"

Comment: Well, in that case it may be best to do it in a directive, here is an updated fiddle with the directive now doing the manipulation dependent on the RGB colour passed through: http://jsfiddle.net/skriblez/dqfwvyso/2/

Comment: So i have to add a directive to every element which i want to interact with ? from my javascript code ?

Comment: The directive is reusable and has its own isolated scope. So  you can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/skriblez/dqfwvyso/4/

Comment: brilliant :) put that in an answer and you get an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a directive to achieve this.

```
.directive('box', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            rgb: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('rgb', function () {
                angular.element(elem).css('background-color', 'rgb(' + scope.rgb + ')');
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of you to use the directive: http://jsfiddle.net/skriblez/dqfwvyso/4/